# Performance implications of &p[0] vs. p.get() in boost::scoped_array

Tags: c++, performance, boost

The topic generically says it all. Basically in a situation like this:

```
boost::scoped_array<int> p(new int[10]);
```

Is there any appreciable difference in performance between doing: `&p[0]` and `p.get()`?

I ask because I prefer the first one, it has a more natural pointer like syntax. In fact, it makes it so you could replace p with a native pointer or array and not have to change anything else.

I am guessing since get is a one liner "`return ptr;`" that the compiler will inline that, and I hope that it is smart enough to to inline `operator[]` in such a way that it is able to not dereference and then immediately reference.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've done some basic tests as per Martin York's suggestions.

It seems that g++ (4.3.2) is actually pretty good about this. At both -O2 and -O3 optimization levels, it outputs slightly different but functionally equivalent assembly for both `&p[0]` and `p.get()`.

At -Os as expected, it took the path of least complexity and emits a call to the `operator[]`. One thing to note is that the `&p[0]` version does cause g++ to emit a copy of the `operator[]` body, but it is never used, so there is a slight code bloat if you never use `operator[]` otherwise:

The tested code was this (with the `#if` both 0 and 1):

```
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    boost::scoped_array<int> p(new int[10]);
#if 1
    printf("%p\n", &p[0]);
#else
    printf("%p\n", p.get());
#endif
}
```

Comment: Did you define `NDEBUG`? I’m not sure how `BOOST_ASSERT` is triggered/deactivated but normal assertions get completely deactivated when `NDEBUG` is defined and then the exact same code should be emitted on high optimization for the reason mentioned by Martin (and the assumption that `&*ptr == ptr`).

Comment: Wow, good call, the asm is *identical* with -DNDEBUG, if you provide an answer containing that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know is to actually measure it!

But if you have the source of the boost:scoped_array you could llok at the code and see what it does. I am sure it is pretty similar.

```
T * scoped_array::get() const // never throws
{
    return ptr;
}

T & scoped_array::operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i) const // never throws
{
    BOOST_ASSERT(ptr != 0);
    BOOST_ASSERT(i >= 0);
    return ptr[i];
}
```

Write two versions of the code (one using get() the other using operator[]). Compile to assembley with optimizations turned on. See if your compiler actually manages to optimize away the ptr+0.

Comment: I have looked at the source, operator[] basically just does a "return ptr[i];" (there are some asserts, but that's the code that matters). My question is, is the compiler smart enough to know that &ptr[0] == ptr in this case of using the operator[] function.

Comment: You are asking if the compiler is smart enough to optimise away 'ptr + 0'. Check the output of your compiler.

Comment: heh, you could just say "i don't know" :-P. Anyway, I know if p was a native pointer it could. I suppose if the param of operator[] is known at compile time it *should* be able to factor it all. I wonder if it does.

Comment: I would rather say it is impossable to know the answer without more exact information. Since this is easy for you to do all by yourself, maybe its somthing you should try by hand ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a question you're asking just for academic interest or is this for some current code you're writing?

In general, people recommend that code clarity is more important that speed, so unless your sure this is going to make a difference you should pick whichever option is clearer and matches your code base.  FWIW, I personally think that the get() is clearer.

Comment: Mostely academic reasons. It was a curiosity that occurred to me when added some smart pointers to some older code. I realized that using &p[0] meant less changes cause it works with regular pointers too.